# How can I fix the background image height to 50% inside a flex div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want my background image to take 50% of the div and the rest 50% to be text (the birthday text message) below it in a div which has `flex-direction:column`. Currently, the background image changes its height automatically (sometimes more than 50%, sometimes less than 50%) based on screen size, but I want it to always take 50% height with the "Birthday card image (Happy Birthday)" overlapping the envelope in the background as shown in the screenshot below, and the rest 50% for the text (birthday wish). How can I achieve that?

*HTML file*

```
<section class="normal-page">
      <section class="e-greeting-design">
        <div class="first-half">
          <div class="first-half__bg-wrapper"> <img src="/assets/images/egreetingbg.png"></div>
          <div class="first-half__img-wrapper"><img src="/assets/images/card-egreeting.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-half">
          <div class="second-half__content-wrapper"><span>To:&nbsp; </span><span class="text-bold">Andy Raey</span>
            <p class="text-bold">Happy Birthday! May you celebrate your 35th with all who are dear to you.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
```

*SCSS File*

```
.e-greeting-design {
    
    width: 90%;
    background-color: white;    
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
    max-width: 1280px;

    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 20px;

    > * {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }

    .first-half {
        position: relative;

        &__bg-wrapper{
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
 
        }  

        &__img-wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            padding: 50px;
            width: 70%;
        }

        img {
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    }

    .second-half {
        &__content-wrapper{
            max-width: 75%;
            margin: 80px 60px;

            > span,> p{
            font-size: 32px;
            color: #5C068C;

            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 32px;
            
            }


            p {
                
                    margin-top:48px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    line-height: 32px;
                
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

*Current output*

[image]

*How I want it to look like *

[image]

Comment: Please add a working example using the code snippet

Comment: @Sfili_81 what do you mean? Where is the code snippet to add a working example, I cannot seem to find it. Could you please guide me?

Comment: Click on the button `<>` when create or edit a questione